# Starting an "out of browser Silverlight 4 elevated app" from another "out of browser Silverlight 4 elevated app"

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

I am concurrently running several different out of browser elevated applications and sending messages between them.

Is there a way for me to check to see if a specific one of those elevated out of browser Silverlight apps are currently running and if not programmatically start that app for the user?  preferably without automation.  If via automation, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Tim Heuer's post http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx on how you can launch OOB applications. It would be necessary to use automation to run sllauncher.exe. As for detecting if OOB aplication is allready running I'd look to local messaging api. I haven't worked with it myself, so I can only suggest to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Denis. I have played around with each of those options.

1. Detecting using messaging. This works fine.  Each app has a "ping/discovery" send/receive channel.  Each app can now easily determine which other apps are running by message responses or lack there of.  It feels a bit kludgey but it works.

2. I've previously read that blog from Tim. I have started to look into Automating SLauncher.exe. It's not working yet but I think it can - will keep you posted. My concern with this is that I cannot get it to work on a Mac yet. 

Still looking for a better (programmatic) launching approach.

Answer (score 1):

After continuing to search for answers on this problem I finally found this post: [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/157670/355145.aspx)

It is a bit of a hack and will not work on a Mac (for now) but it's a start.

I thought I would share it back in case others here were interested.

Comment: And this it why it sucks when people just post a link.  Its no longer valid.